# XSLT namespace prevents an identity transform with changes in the output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm performing an XSLT 2.0 identity transform on some EAD (Encoded Archival Description) XML documents. I need to modify the output slightly, but I seem to be running into a namespace issue.

Don't test this in a schema-aware processor, you'll get errors! :)

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="no"/>

<!-- The identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="filedesc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <header>Subjects</header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample-EAD.xml (also available on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/RFAQaY3w)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ead xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd"     xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511" countryencoding="iso3166-1" dateencoding="iso8601" langencoding="iso639-2b">  
<eadid>01234</eadid>
<filedesc>
    <AAA>1</AAA>
    <BBB>2</BBB>
</filedesc>
</eadheader>
<archdesc>
    <bib>
        <CCC>1</CCC>
        <DDD>2</DDD>
    </bib>
</archdesc>
 </ead>
```

If I pull out the namespace information from the  element, (also available here: http://pastebin.com/6ygi3xUm) the identity transform w/ modifications works.

Sample-EAD-2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ead>

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511" countryencoding="iso3166-1" dateencoding="iso8601" langencoding="iso639-2b">  
<eadid>01234</eadid>
<filedesc>
    <AAA>1</AAA>
    <BBB>2</BBB>
</filedesc>
</eadheader>
<archdesc>
    <bib>
        <CCC>1</CCC>
        <DDD>2</DDD>
    </bib>
</archdesc>
```

I'm not very good with namespaces so any advice would be greatly appreciated. If I try adding the namespaces to the XSLT, the transform works but I get namespace attributes in the new elements. Thanks very much for reading & your suggestions!
Cheers!

EDIT:
input (w/namespaces), run through identity transform results --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ead xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511"
          countryencoding="iso3166-1"
          dateencoding="iso8601"
          langencoding="iso639-2b"> 
     <eadid>01234</eadid>
     <filedesc>
           <AAA>1</AAA>
           <BBB>2</BBB>
     </filedesc>
  </eadheader>
  <archdesc>
        <bib>
              <CCC>1</CCC>
              <DDD>2</DDD>
        </bib>
  </archdesc>
</ead>
```

input (w/o namespaces) run through identity transform results --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ead>

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511"
          countryencoding="iso3166-1"
          dateencoding="iso8601"
          langencoding="iso639-2b"> 
     <eadid>01234</eadid>
     <filedesc>
     <header>Subjects</header>
           <AAA>1</AAA>
           <BBB>2</BBB>
     </filedesc>
  </eadheader>
  <archdesc>
        <bib>
              <CCC>1</CCC>
              <DDD>2</DDD>
        </bib>
  </archdesc>
```

and finally, the input (w/ namespaces) run through the XSLT (with namespaces added) results --

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="no"/>

<!-- The identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="filedesc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <header>Subjects</header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ead xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511"
          countryencoding="iso3166-1"
          dateencoding="iso8601"
          langencoding="iso639-2b"> 
     <eadid>01234</eadid>
     <filedesc>
           <AAA>1</AAA>
           <BBB>2</BBB>
     </filedesc>
  </eadheader>
  <archdesc>
        <bib>
              <CCC>1</CCC>
              <DDD>2</DDD>
        </bib>
  </archdesc>
</ead>
```

EDIT #2:
Apologies, all, as I think I've failed to express my desired output. I would like to avoid additional attributes in the modified elements, as additional processing will take place after the identity transform and I'd like to keep the XML as close to it's current state as possible (except for the edits). Thanks again for your patience & help! Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ead xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<eadheader findaidstatus="Ready_for_online" repositoryencoding="iso15511" countryencoding="iso3166-1" dateencoding="iso8601" langencoding="iso639-2b">  
    <eadid>01234</eadid>
    <filedesc>
        <header>List Name</header>
        <AAA>1</AAA>
        <BBB>2</BBB>
    </filedesc>
</eadheader>
<archdesc>
    <bib>
        <CCC>1</CCC>
        <DDD>2</DDD>
    </bib>
</archdesc>
</ead>
```

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting and point out which attributes you have questions about?

Comment: hi Colin D, I've added additional examples. Please let me know if I can provide more information! Thanks!

Comment: I believe the `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` is the problem, only list the prefixes that you really want to exclude.

Comment: hi biziclop, thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to help. Adding the <header> element to <filedesc> still doesn't work.

Comment: So the attributes you are concerned about are the "xmlns:*" attributes? What is the reason you want them excluded from the output?

Comment: @ColinD I've edited the examples again - sorry for the confusion. There's quite a bit more processing that will take place after this identity transform & I'd like to avoid adding new attributes. Maybe that's a none-issue, though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very long question and a bit hard to follow, but I think this is what you want. The deal is that the element you want to match is in a namespace in the source xml document, so you have to match the namespace too. Thus I've assigned a prefix to it in the xslt: `xmlns:input="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"` I then use it to match the filedesc element: `<xsl:template match="input:filedesc">`. I also make the same namespace be the default namespace for the xsl so your  element will be in that namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:input="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"
    xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9"
    exclude-result-prefixes="input"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="no"/>

  <!-- The identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="input:filedesc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <header>Subjects</header>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi David -- thanks for the response. I received a similar answer via another help forum. I really appreciate the assistance! Cheers!